# How can I say the words "both" and "same" in Ukrainian?

Tags: переклад

Ok, so I've been googling through Ukrainian language sites and I can't find a consensus on the word "both". Some say *оба*, others *обоє* and others *обидва*. I won't try to guess which one is right or the most used. So if anyone could give me the most used along with its declension, I would be very thankful.

Also, when I say "same" (I mean as in "the same person", "the same city", not the adverb as in "I think the same"). So again, if anyone could tell me how to say it along with a declension table, I would be very thankful ^^.

Comment: The Ukrainian for "both" has 18 forms depending on the gender and case of the noun following it and on whether it is collective. "The same" has 2 variants and each variant has 24 forms depending on the number, gender, and case of the noun following, 24×2=48. Which of the forms do you need? Or do you need them all? Or do you need to translate a particular sentence? Anyway, we don't do translation here, your question as it is now will be most probably put on hold. Try to rewrite it showing what previous research you've done. And don't tell us no English-Ukrainian dictionary is available to you.

Answer (score 4):

<sub>Source: [«Словники України on-line»](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/dictua/).</sub>

## «Both»

```
Grammatical   | Masculine | Masculine  | Feminine | Mixed
case and etc. |           | (dated /   |          | 
              |           | dialectal) |          | 
--------------+-----------+------------+----------+------
Nom.          | оби́два    | оба́        | оби́дві   | обо́є
--------------+-----------+------------+----------+------
Gen.          |                  обо́х
--------------+------------------------------------------
Dat.          |                  обо́м
-----+--------+------------------------------------------
     |anim.   |                  обо́х
Acc. +--------+-----------+------------+----------+------
     |unanim. | оби́два    | оба́        | оби́дві   | обо́є
-----+--------+-----------+------------+----------+------
Ins.          |                  обо́ма
--------------+------------------------------------------
Loc.          |                  обо́х
--------------+-----------+------------+----------+------
Voc.          | оби́два    | оба́        | оби́дві   | обо́є
```

Often people say «о́ба» (like in dated masculine «оба́», but with different stress), but it is considered to be non-standard (probably, [surzhyk](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surzhyk)).